# How to "log customer in" in through BigCommerce and give them access to a custom website

Tags: bigcommerce

I have an existing website that uses Bigcommerce and I have a large customer list. I want to be able to give all of my customers access to a secondary website using their same login/password that they use to log into my BigCommerce website. Is there a way for me to let them login to BigCommerce and my website can verify that that customer is who they say they are?

This would be very useful for my high value customers who want a custom portal that I cannot build into BigCommerce because I don't have access to the PHP code so I need my own server running custom code for them. I am imagining something like how Facebook login works with OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this!

It takes a bit of backend knowledge, but there's some cool things going on to get this to work.

1. Setup a web application at your customer url, however ensure the customer url is https://*.yourwebstore.com where your store url is https://www.yourwebstore.com (the https is necessary)
2. When a logged in BC user hits your website grab their cookies, specifically this one: SHOP_TOKEN now this cookie will ONLY get sent if you are HTTPS, so ensure you are HTTPS
3. Next take the cookie and spoof a web request to bigcommerce and in return read the cookies again! BC will send you a cookie with your customerId.
4. Use that customerID to look the customer up in the BC database to find their email and now you can log them into your system as well.

I did some further checking as well in my system for security reasons, but I won't go into that here, pm me if you need more info on other ways to super securely grab your BC user into your customer auth portal.

Answer (score 0):

In the BC backend you have the ability to setup Customer Groups, I would recommend using them to your advantage. You can setup a Customer Group and a Category that only the customers in that group have access too. This way no one else will see the products in that group. However this can be a pain if you have a bunch of products since you can't specify pricing based off customer group. You have to have a separate product just for that customer.  I know its not exactly the answer your looking for but it will work. hope this helps

Comment: This is close, but it's not a truly custom portal. I need a key or something on my end that shows a customer is securely logged into bigcommerce so they can view their orders, etc. on my own server, not on bigcommerce's server.

Comment: I am thinking you might want to look at some type of SSO (Single Sign On).

Comment: That's exactly right. I don't think BC offers any type of SSO though.

Comment: I am not really sure if anyone will be able to integrate with BC on that level. I would recommend calling them and talking to a support representative.

Comment: I just posted how I solved this, it took a few months of critical thinking, but we have it working really well on our store now.

Comment: Great, glad you found a way. Care to share the code you are using so I can look?

Comment: I posted a response that details "how" but no code because I'm on Node JS, and the how is a bit more platform agnostic. The key is to grab your cookies by being HTTPS.