# How can I get the id of logged in customer from a private app with bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to find a way to get the id of the current visitor logged into my bigcommerce store from a subdomain of my store.

I can see cookies set like SHOP_TOKEN etc but nothing for a customer id. I have searched for hours and found this that didn't work form me - [How to "log customer in" in through BigCommerce and give them access to a custom website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785598/how-to-log-customer-in-in-through-bigcommerce-and-give-them-access-to-a-custom/32149516#32149516)

I appreciate the help

Comment: Where are you trying to get the id?  On the serve side or in the user's web browser?

Comment: On the server side of a different site which is not big commerce but supports php. It is a subdomain of the big commerce store and is over ssl so i can read cookies set in big commerce

Comment: Why not set your own cookie on the Bigcommerce store immediately after the user logs in. For security, you should generate a random hash, and store it in a separate DB, so when you read the cookie on your external app, you can read the cookie, grab the email, and verify the hash for authenticity. Afterwards, you can make an API call with the email as a query parameter to grab the internally assigned customer ID. At the end of the day, all solutions are client-side so it's hard to retain best security.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the SHOP_TOKEN is encoded somehow on Bigcommerce's side, it won't return the customer's ID in the clear.

If you can work with a client-side solution, you can grab the ID from the DOM.  Just add a data attribute equal to %%GLOBAL_CustomerId%% to a DOM element that exists globally...maybe the HTML document element:

```
<html lang="en" class=....data-customer="%%GLOBAL_CustomerId%%">
```

You could then grab this value easily in JS, if that would be a fit for your needs.

Comment: I can't do what i need to securely on the client side but i appreciate your suggestion thanks